# Typing L with stroke with us-intl-altgr

Tags: keyboard-layout, internationalization

How do I type an [L with stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81) or ł, which appears notably in Polish, when using the `us-intl-altgr` keyboard mapping for X? More generally, is there a way to find out systematically how I can produce a certain symbol with a given keymap?

I have searched online and found several illustrations of this layout, but none seems to include this symbol.

Comment: Btw: the keyboard layout can be seen with `gkbd-keyboard-display -l "us(altgr-intl)"`. There's no `ł` shown, though. :-( I'd suggest to press `CTRL-SHIFT-u` so an underlined `u` appears to indicate Unicode. Then let go of the keys and type `0141` (for `Ł`) or `0142` (for `ł`).

Comment: @PerlDuck That interface does not display all the symbols that can be entered, though, For instance, using deadkeys I can type another Polish character, ę (AltGr+8 then e), but it's not shown by gkbd-keyboard-display. Actually, it seems to me that it shows certain characters at `...`, and it does not highlight deadkeys at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question after some research.

A list of defined keys is in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. The character ł appears there as `lstroke`, and it is unfortunately not defined in the `altgr-intl` section, unfortunately (but only in `colemak`).

A different way to obtain it would be with the [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) `dead_stroke` followed by `l`. Unfortunately, the key `dead_stroke` isn't defined in `altgr-intl` either (but only in `mac`). So the answer is that there is no way to enter that symbol with the "vanilla" `altgr-intl` apart from the cumbersome method described in [@GunnarHjalmarsson's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035776/184909), which allows to enter a generic Unicode codepoint: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, 0142, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

There is a different solution, though: defining a [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key). Using `gnome-tweaks`, one can set up a modifier key (for instance, right-alt, or caps lock) to act as a compose key. Then, pressing <kbd>compose</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>  produces ł.

Comment: Right, a compose key is one way, but you probably don't want to define <Right Alt> as the compose key when using the `us+altgr-intl` layout, since that would make all the 3:rd and 4:th level symbols unavailable (unless you also define another `lv3:` option).

Answer (score 3):

A generic method to type a character, which is not present with the keyboard layout you are using, is to [type it using its code points](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#ctrlshiftu).

So for the example you mentioned:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+U followed by 0142 followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> => ł

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to know which characters are present in the keyboard layout? Something like `dumpkeys` for the tty console.